# Problems binding a radio button group in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a bit of trouble using a radio button group in my **ASP.NET Core 3.0 Razor** page. Essentially, I want to use a radio group instead of a select, but I've no idea how to bind it to my InputModel properly.

[Code](https://github.com/Atulin/Ogma/tree/master/Ogma3/Pages/Editors) for the Razor Page in question. And the rest of the code in the repo, of course.

In my `cshtml.cs` I have an input model defined like so

```cs
public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(
        CTConfig.Story.MaxTitleLength,
        ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.",
        MinimumLength = CTConfig.Story.MinTitleLength
    )]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(
        CTConfig.Story.MaxDescriptionLength,
        ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.",
        MinimumLength = CTConfig.Story.MinDescriptionLength
    )]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(
        CTConfig.Story.MaxHookLength,
        ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.",
        MinimumLength = CTConfig.Story.MinHookLength
    )]
    public string Hook { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [MaxFileSize(CTConfig.Story.CoverMaxWeight)]
    [AllowedExtensions(new[] {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"})]
    public IFormFile Cover { get; set; }
    [Required] 
    public Rating Rating { get; set; }
    [Required] 
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

and the radio button group in the `.cshtml` file looks as follows:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Rating</label>
    <p>The age rating</p>

    @foreach (var rating in Model.Ratings)
    {
        <div class="form-check">
            <input asp-for="Input.Rating" class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="@rating.Name.ToLower()" value="@rating.Id" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="@rating.Name.ToLower()">@rating.Name</label>
        </div>
    }
    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Rating" class="text-warning"></span>   
</div>
```

and the request, when form is sent, looks [correct](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/156079822454390784/635662345733013535/unknown.png) as well.

But if I write out the errors

```cs
foreach (var msv in ModelState.Values)
{
    foreach (var error in msv.Errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
The Rating field is required.
```

written out to the console.

Comment: You may need the [Bindproperty] Tag unless you have [BindProperties] outside of the pasted code.Something that may get confusing is having the Model Properties named exactly the same as the class. Instead of `Rating Rating` it may be beneficial to have `Rating FormRating`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an `int Rating` instead of full `Rating Rating` in the `InputModel` seems to have solved the issue.